# How to configure dbms_metadata.get_ddl to add 'ASC' after every column of the index?

Tags: oracle, ddl, dbms-metadata

Hello I am trying to export some indexes from a schema and I am using dbms_metadata.get_ddl

So far the indexes are exported like this

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "TEST" ON "TABLE" (ROUND("COLUMN1") , NVL("COLUMN2",0) , NVL("COLUMN3",0) , "YEAR" , "DAY");  but I would like after each column to specify ASC/DESC
```

So the index would look like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "TEST" ON "TABLE" (ROUND("COLUMN1") ASC, NVL("COLUMN2",0) ASC, NVL("COLUMN3",0) ASC, "YEAR" ASC, "DAY" ASC);
```

Is there any way I can configure it to look like this?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi. please edit the question and show how you are calling dbms_metadata.